# ENSwiftSideMenu when I go back my previous screen data of text field disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Hello I am using EnSwiftSideMenu library (https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu). I have two independent view controller that uses side menu. When button pressed from first VC it is doing following code

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var destinationVC:UIViewController!
    destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SicilBilgileriVC") as! SicilBilgileriVC
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destinationVC)
    hideSideMenuView()
```

When I pressed back button from my second vc it is triggering following code to go back first VC.

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

```
    var destinationVC:UIViewController!
    destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SicilBilgileriVC") as! SicilBilgileriVC
    sideMenuController()?.setContentViewController(destinationVC)
    hideSideMenuView()
```

However, inputs that I have added first VC has been gone somehow. I need to keep them even if user pressed back button? I also tried pushing two of VC's but I could not be successful. Where am I missing?

Comment: This is not disappearing. You are instantiating again your VC. So it is a brand new VC appearing for you.

Comment: If I don't instantiate again my side menu does not appear for the second vc. How can I use old one?

Comment: I don't know how this lib you're using works. Maybe it is in the docs. One  way is to have a singleton with your vc as global variable and then you call it from wherever you want

Comment: I have also tried to make it singleton but still text fields data disappearing.